# RSpec: stubbing Kernel::sleep?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is there a way to stub Kernel.sleep in an rspec scenario?

Comment: Are you looking for something beyond Kernel::stubs(:sleep)

Comment: I'd imagine he'd be wanting it to work and not sleep, maybe slowing his test...

Comment: This post is almost 10 years old... no longer relevant

Comment: @WinstonKotzan how exactly is it no longer relevant? Is rspec not used anymore? What did I miss?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you are calling sleep within the context of an object, you should stub it on the object, like so:

```
class Foo
  def self.some_method
    sleep 5
  end
end

it "should call sleep" do
  Foo.stub!(:sleep)
  Foo.should_receive(:sleep).with(5)
  Foo.some_method
end
```

The key is, to stub sleep on whatever "self" is in the context where sleep is called.

Comment: Stubbing the object under test isn't a good idea. For examples, see: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/don-t-stub-the-system-under-test

Comment: @georgebrock for nonrelevant reason, isn't it? I believe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27749263/52499) is the way that conveys intention best. And must be using newer syntax. `allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:sleep)`

Answer (score 29):

When the call to `sleep` is not within an object (while testing a rake task for example), you can add the following in a before block (rspec 3 syntax)

```
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:sleep)
```

Answer (score 5):

In pure rspec:

```
before do
  Kernel.stub!(:sleep)
end

it "should sleep" do
  Kernel.should_receive(:sleep).with(100)
  Object.method_to_test #We need to call our method to see that it is called
end
```

Comment: To clarify, because this didn't work for me immediately, you must call Kernel.sleep, in order to mock it this way.  Just calling sleep directly fails

Comment: Yes, the method you call will have that sleep in it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using [Mocha](http://github.com/jferris/mocha/tree/master), then something like this will work:

```
def setup
  Kernel.stubs(:sleep)
end

def test_my_sleepy_method
  my_object.take_cat_nap!
  Kernel.assert_received(:sleep).with(1800) #should take a half-hour paower-nap
end
```

Or if you're using [rr](http://github.com/btakita/rr/tree/master):

```
def setup
  stub(Kernel).sleep
end

def test_my_sleepy_method
  my_object.take_cat_nap!
  assert_received(Kernel) { |k| k.sleep(1800) }
end
```

You *probably* shouldn't be testing more complex threading issues with unit tests. On integration tests, however, use the real `Kernel.sleep`, which will help you ferret out complex threading issues.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the newer way of stubbing Rspec with `Kernal::Sleep`.

This is basically an update to the following answer: [Tony Pitluga's answer to the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1303832/6735912)

```
class Foo
  def self.some_method
    sleep 5
  end
end

it "should call sleep" do
  allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:sleep)
  expect(Foo).to receive(:sleep).with(5)
  Foo.some_method
end
```

Answer (score 2):

For rspec version 1, the stubbing syntax has changed. This works:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Kernel).to receive(:sleep).and_return("")
```

When I use it.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to stub require and after long searching I found that the only way that worked for me is this

```
def method_using_sleep
  sleep
  sleep 0.01
end

it "should use sleep" do
  @expectations = mock('expectations')
  @expectations.should_receive(:sleep).ordered.with()
  @expectations.should_receive(:sleep).ordered.with(0.01)

  def sleep(*args)
    @expectations.sleep(*args)
  end

  method_using_sleep
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the other solutions here to work. Maybe something have changed in the way sleep is handled in newer versions of Ruby, or something else.

What I ended up doing was to monkey-patch the **Object** class as it appears that this is what receives the sleep calls. So I simply added this:

```
class Object
    def sleep(*args)
    end
end
```

So the sleep method now does nothing in stead of something. There might be some way of mocking this better, but I was not able to find a good solution without mocking the `sleep metohd` of every single object that potentially used it.

Comment: Please see my solution bellow. rspec-mock is here so you don't have to monkey-patch

Answer (score 0):

Since `Kernel` is an ancestor of all Objects, one should be able to mock the inherited `sleep` method on the class under test.

```
MyClass.ancestors --> [MyClass, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

The mock can be accomplished with code similar to this.

```
before do
  allow(described_class).to receive(:sleep).and_return('')
end
```

The following more detailed example shows mocking `sleep` for when it is called within class and instance methods. Would enjoy hearing comments from more experienced Ruby developers.

Class:

```
class MyClass
  class << self
    def klass_action(sleep_seconds)
      sleep(sleep_seconds)
    end
  end

  def self.class_action(sleep_seconds)
    sleep(sleep_seconds)
  end

  def do_some_action(sleep_seconds)
    sleep(sleep_seconds)
  end
end
```

Tests:

```
describe MyClass, focus: true do
  subject { MyClass.new }

  let(:sleep_seconds) { 12 }

  context 'sleep called from an instance' do
    before do
      allow(subject).to receive(:sleep).and_return('')
    end

    it 'sleeps for the requested number of seconds' do
      subject.do_some_action(sleep_seconds)

      expect(subject).to have_received(:sleep).with(sleep_seconds)
    end
  end

  context 'sleep called from a class' do
    before do
      allow(described_class).to receive(:sleep).and_return('')
    end

    it 'class method sleeps for the requested number of seconds' do
      described_class.class_action(sleep_seconds)

      expect(described_class).to have_received(:sleep).with(sleep_seconds)
    end

    it 'klass method sleeps for the requested number of seconds' do
      described_class.klass_action(sleep_seconds)

      expect(described_class).to have_received(:sleep).with(sleep_seconds)
    end
  end
end
```