# RSpec how to stub open?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec

I've been trying to stub `open`, the open-uri version, and I'm not succeeding.

I've tried doing the following but the request keeps going through:

```
Kernel.should_receive(:open).and_return("Whatever for now")
```

I've also tried to do

```
OpenURI::OpenRead.should_receive(:open).and_return("Whatever for now")
```

Since I tracked down that was where HTTP requests were made in OpenURI.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution here on Stack Overflow after some more time on Google (I can't believe I didn't find this before).

Explanation taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168845/rspec-stubbing-kernelsleep/1303832#1303832) and written by **Tony Pitluga** (not linkable).

> If you are calling sleep within the context of an object, you should stub it on the object[...]
>   The key is, to stub sleep on whatever "self" is in the context where sleep is called.

So I did this and it all worked out:

```
let(:read) { mock('open') }

it "should return the new log-level when the log level was set successfully" do
    read.stub(:read).and_return('log-level set to 1')
    kannel.should_receive(:open).and_return(read)

    kannel.set_log_level(1).should == 1
  end
```

Comment: Nice! I think it's reasonable to edit this and post it as the solution for `open()` and accept your own answer. It might be hard to find the `sleep()` article when stubbing `open()`.

Comment: Very good point on stubbing on whatever the context of self is. This helped me solve a similar problem, thanks!

Comment: I've updated your code. Explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11258596/608361

Answer (score 13):

Here is what I do

```
class Gateway

  def do_something
    open('http://example.com').read
  end

end
```

In my spec i do the following:

```
describe 'communication' do

  it 'should receive valid response from example.com' do
    gateway = Gateway.new
    gateway.stub_chain(:open, :read).and_return('Remote server response')

    gateway.do_something.should == "Remote server response"
  end 

end
```

Comment: I think this is a great way around this kind of problem. Thanks for reminding me :)

Comment: Also, `Gateway.any_instance.stub_chain(...)`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using something to stub the network instead. I believe the current favorite for doing so is [FakeWeb](http://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb) [[docs](http://fakeweb.rubyforge.org/)]. You may also be interested in [fakeweb-matcher](http://github.com/freelancing-god/fakeweb-matcher) for rspec.

---

Alas, I think FakeWeb might not work with `open()`, actually, it stubs `Net::HTTP`, so I'm not sure if that will work. Any chance of not using `open()`? :)

Comment: `open()` is a perfect fit for where the code is going so using `Net:HTTP` directly would just feel wrong. :)

I spent some more time on Google and found another Stack Overflow question that helped me out. But thanks for trying!