# How to rspec mock open-uri?

Tags: rspec-rails

I have this simple code where I am sending http request and reading all the response.
Here is my rails code

```
open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
```

How can I write spec for this line of code. I dont have the option to use mocha and webmock. I can only use mocking framework of Rpsec.

I have tried to use this statement

```
OpenURI.stub!(:open_uri).should_receive(:open).with("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
```

but i keep getting this error

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: (#<RSpec::Mocks::MessageExpectation:0xd1a7914>).open("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask")
expected: 1 time
received: 0 times
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I thought that the `open` method is defined on the level of the `Kernel`, but I was wrong.

If you would like to mock the `open`, you should do it on the **level of your object** like this:

```
it "should do something" do
  object_under_test = ObjectUnderTest.new
  object_under_test.should_receive(:open).with("http://example.org")
end
```

Comment: This is nice and you can use   expect(object_under_test).to receive(:open).with(anything).and_return(File.read(File.new(Rails.root.join("spec/fixtures/images/sample.jpeg"))))   to stub out an S3 file-read during a test.

Answer (score 4):

To stub `open-uri` you can use this syntax **RSpec 3+**

```
file = double('file')
expect(OpenURI).to receive(:open_uri).and_return(file)
```

Answer (score 2):

According to this link http://distillations.2rye.com/2011/08/mock-the-web-openuri/ the open function is defined on the Kernel module, but mixed into your controller. Therefore you need to stub the call at that level. This solution works well for RSpec controller tests:

```
  html_content = <<-EOS
          <html><head>
           <title>Some Title</title>
          </head>
          <body>Some Content</body></html>
        EOS

  YourController.any_instance.stub(:open).and_return html_content
```

Answer (score 2):

I did:

```
my_object.stub_chain(:open, :read) { "my return value" }
```

Comment: @Brian Re-format how? What would you like expanded? Using `stub_chain`  like this means you can call `open("whatever").read` within `my_object` and you'll get `"my_return_value"` back.

Comment: you are right.  Your answer was classified as 'low quality' (because of its length) when I was reviewing it. I did some research later that night and it turns out, your answer is correct (despite the brevity).  I have removed the comment and +1'd your answer.  My apologies, sir!

Comment: I am getting a deprecation warning when using stub_chain in Rspec 3.3.1. What is the new :expect syntax for this?