# How do I test this particular method?

Tags: ruby, rspec, nokogiri, open-uri

I have the following method that is responsible for requesting a URL and returning it's `Nokogiri::HTML` document. This method checks if a proxy is defined and if it does, it will call `OpenURI`'s `open` with or without the proxy options.

**Implementation**

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'

class MyClass 
  attr_accessor :proxy

  # ....

  def self.page_content(url)
    if MyClass.proxy
      proxy_uri = URI.parse(MyClass.proxy)
      Nokogiri::HTML(open(url, :proxy => proxy_uri)) # open provided by OpenURI
    else
      Nokogiri::HTML(open(url)) # open provided by OpenURI
    end
  end
end
```

I have no idea how I should write tests that prove the following:

1. When a proxy is defined the request OpenURI makes actually uses the proxy info
2. When a proxy isn't defined, a regular non-proxy connection is made

Here's what I came up with as a start for the tests.

```
describe MyClass, :vcr do

  describe '.proxy' do
    it { should respond_to(:proxy) }
  end

  describe '.page_content' do
    let(:url) { "https://google.com/" }
    let(:page_content) { subject.page_content(url) }

    it 'returns a Nokogiri::HTML::Document' do
      page_content.should be_a(Nokogiri::HTML::Document)
    end

    # How do i test this method actually uses a proxy when it's set vs not set?
    context 'when using a proxy' do
      # ???
      xit 'should set open-uri proxy properties' do
      end
    end

    context 'when not using a proxy' do
      # ???
      xit 'should not set open-uri proxy properties' do
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Comment: What does the `open` refer to in your implementation?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin `open` is provided by OpenURI. I will comment the code to make that explicitly stated.

Comment: Do you want to actually open the URI and call Nokogiri as part of your test or do you want to just make sure you are making those calls (i.e. using stubs)?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I don't know the answer to that question. I'm sorry -- this is very new to me.  I think the answer is i just want to make sure i'm making those calls.  I don't know if it should be via stubs though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to arrange for the `proxy` method to return a proxy in one test case and not in the other. If there is a "setter" method for proxy, you can use that, otherwise you can stub the `proxy` method.

Then, at a minimum, you want to set an expectation on `open` that it will be called with or without the `:proxy` option, depending on which test it is. Beyond that, you have the choice of whether to stub and set expectations for the various other calls involved in the method, including `URI.parse` and `Nokogiri::HTML`.

See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks for information on establishing your test doubles and setting expectations. Note in particular the `and_call_original` option if you want to use a partial stubbing approach.

Update: Here's some code to get you started. This works for the non-proxy method.  I've left the proxy case for you. Note also that this uses the "partial stubbing" approach, where you still end up calling the external gems.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MyClass do

  describe '.proxy' do         # NOTE: This test succeeds because of attr_accessor, but you're calling a MyClass.proxy (a class method) within your page_content method
    it { should respond_to(:proxy) }
  end

  describe '.page_content' do
    let(:url) { "https://google.com/" }
    let(:page_content) { MyClass.page_content(url) } # NOTE: Changed to invoke class method

    context 'when not using a proxy' do

      before {allow(MyClass).to receive(:proxy).and_return(false)} # Stubbed for no-proxy case

      it 'returns a Nokogiri::HTML::Document' do
        page_content.should be_a(Nokogiri::HTML::Document)
      end

      it 'should not set open-uri proxy properties' do
        expect(MyClass).to receive(:open).with(url).and_call_original  # Stubbing open is tricky, see note afterwards
        page_content
      end
    end
        # How do i test this method actually uses a proxy when it's set vs not set?
    context 'when using a proxy' do
      # ???
      xit 'should set open-uri proxy properties' do
      end
    end

  end

end
```

Stubbing of `open` is tricky.  See [How to rspec mock open-uri?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796986/how-to-rspec-mock-open-uri/11258596#11258596) for an explanation.

Comment: I have updated my question to show there is an `attr_accessor` for `proxy`.  Your first paragraph makes sense; thank you.  What you said about using mocks and `and_call_original` does not make sense, unfortunately.  I have actually read the documentation and skimmed the rspec book but i'm having trouble understanding what objects to mock and would love to see code if possible. thank you!

Comment: `attr_accessor` gives you setters and getters for *instance variables*. You're referencing `proxy` via a class method by the same name.

Comment: You've also defined `page_content` to be `subject.page_content(...)`, but `subject` is implicitly a new *instance* of `MyClass` and there is no `page_content` instance method. In general, if you start executing your spec, RSpec will tell you what you've gotten wrong and if you get stuck, you can get help here.