# How to mock out calls to open-uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, tdd

I've got a mailer that uses 'open-uri'.

```
require 'open-uri'
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome(picasa_picture)
    picture = picasa_picture.content.src
    filename = picture.split('/').last
    attachments.inline[filename] = open(picture).read
    mail(
      to: 'foo@exmample.com',
      from: 'bar@example.com',
      subject: 'hi',
    )
  end
end
```

But when I try and test anything the class, I get this error:

```
 SocketError:
   getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
```

I found this SO post: [How to rspec mock open-uri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796986/how-to-rspec-mock-open-uri) and thought it would help.  I gave this a try:

```
let(:pic_content) { double(:pic_content, src: 'http://www.picasa/asdf/asdf.jpeg') }
let(:picture) { double(:picture, content: pic_content) }
let(:open_uri_mock) { double(:uri_mock, read: true) }

subject { described_class.welcome(picture) }

it 'renders email address of sender' do
  subject.stub(:open).and_return(open_uri_mock)
  subject.from.should == [ sender_address ]
end
```

I also tried a 'should_receive' instead of 'stub', but it didn't help.

How do I suppress the open-uri 'open' method so that it (1) doesn't try to go out to internet and (2) doesn't break my tests?

Comment: I am not sure you're stubbing the right object's open method here

Comment: as far as i can tell you're stubbing after you've called the method so it won't work

Comment: this post seems to think you DO stub on kernal: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3603256/rspec-how-to-stub-open

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not refactor:

```
require 'open-uri'
class NotificationMailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def welcome(picasa_picture)
    picture = picasa_picture.content.src
    filename = picture.split('/').last
    attachments.inline[filename] = open_and_read(picture)
    mail(
      to: 'foo@exmample.com',
      from: 'bar@example.com',
     subject: 'hi',
    )
  end

  def open_and_read(picture)
    open(picture).read
  end

end
```

Then you can stub and test:

```
subject { NotificationMailer }

before do 
  subject.stub(:open_and_read).and_return(:whatever_double_you_want)
  subject.welcome(picture)
end

it 'renders email address of sender' do
  subject.from.should == [ sender_address ]
end
```

Comment: beautiful. Nice solution.  I had to go with `described_class.any_instance.stub(:open_and_read).with(picture).and_return('picture_as_url')` to make it work, but all tests pass now.  Thanks!

Comment: probably also want to go with newer rspec syntax: ```expect(subject.from).to eq([ sender_address ])```

Answer (score 0):

Use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock). It has a pretty straightforward readme so leaving to it. In general it works like:

```rb
stub_request(:post, "www.example.com").
  with(body: "abc", headers: { 'Content-Length' => 3 })

# for rspec
expect(WebMock).to have_requested(:get, "www.example.com").
  with(body: "abc", headers: {'Content-Length' => 3}).twice
```