# Rspec command line test

Tags: ruby, rspec

Currently a I am build has the following two lines which I want to create a unit test for:

```
system @command.join(' ')
exit $?.exitstatus
```

Now I know I can do something like this:

```
Kernel.should_receive(:system).with()
Kernel.should_receive(:exit).with(0)
```

However when gem calls `$?.exitstatus` I've been unable to mock/stub this.

Does anyone know how to do this??

Answer (score 1):

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168845/rspec-stubbing-kernelsleep)

You should stub not `Kernel`, you should stub `system` from the current class.

for example

```
#user.rb
def self.my_test
  system('ls')
end

#test
User.should_receive(:system).and_return('aaa')
User.my_test # => 'aaa'
```

Do not forget to use stub for `any_instance` if it is called not in class scope

Comment: Hi,

Gave this ago and now it works as intended with the following, in my case anyhow:

`Cukesparse.should_receive(:system).with('test')`
`Cukesparse.should_receive(:exit)`

Cheers,
Jon