# Stub sleep with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sleep, stub

I have the following code in my app:

```
def timeout_tasks
  10.times do
    # Work...
    sleep 2
  end
end
```

I would like to test this method, but need to stub `sleep` to I don't have to wait that much for the test to finish.

How can I do this? I am aware of the `allow(Object).to receive(:sleep)` but I'm not sure what the `Object` is. Or is there any other better approach?

Comment: I believe this question is already answered: [stubbing kernel sleep](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168845/rspec-stubbing-kernelsleep)

Comment: Saw that one but couldn't help in my case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should stub sleep on the object it is called on

Eg.

```
class SleepTest
  def sleep_method
    sleep 2
  end
end
```

And in your test

```
sleep_test = SleepTest.new
allow(sleep_test).to receive(:sleep)
```

Answer (score 0):

I looks like  the [sleep](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/sleep) method is defined in [Kernel](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel) so that would be your Object.