# Stubbing sleep method with Rspec.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have method that looks like this:

```
until panel_import.completed?
  panel_import.update_status
  sleep 1.minute
end
```

Now when I run my specs I must wait 1 minute which is bad. How can I stub it? I was reading through many topics but I didn't find solution for that...

Comment: I'd expect the naive way to work: `allow(instance).to receive(:sleep)`

Comment: checkout this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168845/rspec-stubbing-kernelsleep

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stub sleep with RSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32399175/stub-sleep-with-rspec)

Answer (score 3):

As [@Rubyrider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/751716/rubyrider) mentioned, this link offers good help: [RSpec: stubbing Kernel::sleep?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168845/rspec-stubbing-kernelsle%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bep)

To sum up that answer, you can allow the class where `sleep` is called to receive the `sleep` method:

```
# Class that calls `sleep`
class Foo
  def run
    sleep 5
  end
end

# Specs
...
describe '#run' do
  before { allow_any_instance_of(Foo).to receive(:sleep) }

  # your tests
end
```

This will mock the sleep method and prevent it from being run during these tests.

While you could also check for `Rails.env.test?` in your code where you call `sleep` as [@MilesStanfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3123370/milesstanfield) suggested, I always try to stay clear of having code related to my tests in my regular code.

Answer (score 1):

If it were me, i would just add a `Rails.env.test?` so your tests don't run the sleep call.  Like this ...

```
until panel_import.completed?
  panel_import.update_status
  sleep 1.minute unless Rails.env.test?
end
```